# Duplicate client ids - possible ddos on rabbitmq

Tags: ddos

We are using RabbitMQ 3.9.5

There is a number of mqtt users that are being created. Each of these users is allowed to send data to its own topic. These users are not supposed to see data of other users.

The topic is /spm/{username}/data So the permissions of the users have {username} in configure regexp, topic permissions on amq.topic are {username} on write and read.

In order to connect these users have to use a client_id which is equal to the username.

This works so far but: a compromised client can ddos the connection of other users by using their client_id as the existing connection with a duplicate client_id will be terminated.

Is there a way to mitigate this "attack"?